# Why can't we access static method through the object in .net

Tags: c#

with the following code:

```
public class test
{
    public static void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test");
    }
}

public class test2
{
    public test2()
    {
        var a = new test();
        a.DoSomething(); // invalid
        test.DoSomething(); // is valid
    }
}
```

I need to access the static method through the base class, and not through the instance.

But, what would have been the downside of letting the user access it through the instance? It seems to me that it would help with readability.

Comment: It would be kind of confusing IMHO, at least this way you know it is static. Anyway as to the why, its just because someone made that decision. There is no other reason really.

Comment: No, it doesn't help readability. `a.DoSomething();` suggests you are calling an instance method, which could change the state of the object or work on/with the object data in some way. A static method is not working with/on the object instance `a`, so purely from a code readibility/maintainablity perspective, what you want just makes things more error-prone since it goes against intuition/expectations when reading the code...

Comment: "It seems to me that it would help with readability." How would this help? How would you differentiate between a static member call and a non-static one if this were allowed?

Comment: Make an extension method if you really want to do that, though it would be failing my code review

Comment: @HimBromBeere: I don't need to differentiate in all cases; and that's exactly the point I'm thinking about: in some cases, knowing you're explicitly calling a static method does matter, but in other cases it doesn't make any difference and I don't understand why using the instance is not allowed since you could also call a method on an instance that doesn't modify anything, behaving like a static

Comment: Anything being static means that it has only one instance, a function is also something in memory. Because of this, instances of "test" can not have their own function "DoSomething()". Only "test" itself can have the "DoSomething()" function, and that's why you call it from "test" itself. Considering that each instance of "test" also is "a test", one could argue that each instance of "test" should be able to call the function, however in a multi threaded context this could go wrong by multiple instances of "test" trying to execute the same function at the same time.

Comment: Well, the compiler doesn´t know for sure if or if not your method is non-static while it doesn´t change the instances state. It would need very much checks to verifiy if your method **really** does not change the state.

Comment: For example if you would assume multiple instances of "test" can call the static function, in a multithreaded environment, assume the following situation: Instance 1 calls "DoSomething()", Instance 2 calls "DoSomething()" aswell. In the middle of writing "test" in DoSomething(), it starts getting written again. The final output is "tteesstt" for example. This is just an example but maybe you get the point.

Comment: Imagine a new developer saw `test a = null;
        a.StaticMethod();
        a.InstanceMethod();` Would it be obvious to them why the first line of code works but the second doesn't? No it wouldn't - that is why it isn't allowed. _Now admittedly extension methods weaken this argument somewhat - but extension methods are less commonly used than normal methods, and were not a feature of C# from day one like static methods were._

Comment: Making something available on an instance-level that simply has no instance-semantics sounds like a good idea in your world?

Comment: Hrm i think this question should be closed, as stated its not answerable in its current format. Also i am not sure why everyone is upvoting everything, maybe its left over of the xmass break

Comment: In the scenario I'm looking it, there is a logger that has some instance data used by a part of the API but also some code which doesn't care about the instance data. Using it by mixing instance calls and static calls is confusing because it reads as if we're talking to two different systems while the output goes to the same place

Comment: "_knowing you're explicitly calling a static method does matter,_" So, you agree it it is beneficial if the compiler requires/enforces the pattern `<Type>.<StaticMethod>`, even if in some other situations you would know what is a static and what is not a static method, right? "_call a method on an instance that doesn't modify anything, behaving like a static_" That is no reason or generally meaningful example. (1/2)

Comment: I think you actually have a separation of concerns issue (just a guess)

Comment: for example var L = new Logger();...   L.Log(this stuff); Logger.Logx(other stuff) in the code is not as readable as accessing everything through L

Comment: (2/2)An instance method is _supposed_ to be associated (work on) the instance it is called on. That's why instance methods (IM) are instance methods to begin with. If you write an instance method that does not work on the instance it is called on, turn it into a static method. If you have such an IM because it is stipulated by a contract (interface, abstract base class), then such an IM is supposed to work on the instance it is called on, and it would just be down to specific circumstances of the derived class if such a IM would happen to not need to work with the object on which it is called.

Comment: (Addtionally, to add to my (2/2) comment, classes sometimes implement empty _overridable_ methods to keep this class instantiable while giving deriving classes well-defined points to extend the behavior. Again, this does not really mean such methods are not supposed to work on the object. The methods overriding those empty _overrideable_ methods are supposed to work on the object instance they are called on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for every question on a language-decision you allways have to consider the use and the potential harm that is caused by your request. While it may increase your (personal) readability in a very specific case, it adds lots of confusion to readers of your code that don´t have your source-code. Furthermore it would assume a compiler is able to determine if or if not a member actually does something on the instance or not. So the compiler would have far more complicated logic in order to achieve something you can easily indicate yourself by the `static` keyword.

In fact an **instance**-method does something with an **instance**, it does not neccessarily *modifiy* its state, it can also just *use* that state and process some operation. Making something available on that instance-level which does not have instance-semantics seems quite counter-intuituve and breaks the principle of least astonishment - at least for me. If there is a member called on an instance it is **supposed** to do something with that instance. If or if not this is actually the case is an implementation-detail which a client shouldn´t bother for at all.

Comment: I think this is the right answer: In the practical case I am dealing with, it makes syntax much less readable, but in general, it is likely that the separation makes sense.

Answer (score 8):

You can't call a static method from a class instance, because all static fields and methods are associated with the type rather than an instance of said type.

For a deeper understanding of static classes I suggest you read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#static-and-instance-members).

Comment: I would also add, that this is an implementation detail in the C# language specification. Other languages like Python do allow to access static members from an instance.

Comment: That is true. I would only add a link to the offical Microsoft documentation: [static-classes-and-static-class-members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)

Comment: I suggest to add the following link: [static (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static)

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are asking is

> When calling a static method, why we must specify the class that
>   defines the method and when calling an instance method, why we must
>   specify an instance that refers to the object of that class.

To answer this, we must understand how CLR manages things in the background. 
Lets try to understand what happens when a new instance is created:

When we “`new`” up a class’ instance, the CLR creates an object in the `managed heap`, this object on the heap (among other things) also contains the bytes necessary to hold all of the **instance data fields** defined by that class as well as any instance fields defined by any base class (say `Object` class).
This means the instance fields are tied up with that instance of the class that we just created by *newing* up in our code.

Now, when calling a static method, the JIT compiler locates the class object that corresponds to the type that defines the static method. Note that it doesn’t uses the instance (object) here. Then, the JIT compiler locates the entry in the class object’s method table that refers to the method being called, JITs the method (if first time called), and calls the JITted code. 
Notice the difference in how CLR does the discovery of an instance and static methods.

Comment: The question is about why we can't access the static methods from an object; The conclusion from the discussion seems to be that the way it is now makes sense for most cases, and I get why. My point is that in some cases, it makes the code using it less readable since someone consuming an API may not really care about what is static vs. not, but that seems true only in some specific cases.

Comment: @Thomas - I dont think I fully understand your comment. You question suggest that the answser lies on how the CLR manages instance and static methods at runtime, this has nothing to do with code readablity.

Comment: The main point is at the bottom of my question: "But, what would have been the downside of letting the user access it through the instance?" This is a design decision, the CLR was implemented as a consequence, following that design choice.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can create the static method as an extension method on the base class or the child class. And then you can call it directly from the object instance as you attempted.

Answer (score 0):

Using `instance.DoSomething();` would indicate your are calling a method of the instance (which of course would not be true since it is a static class member, not related to the instance iteself). Because of this, it would probably only lead to confusion.

By using `MyClass.DoSomething();` it is easily understood that it is in fact a member of the class (not of an instance) you are calling. Perhaps it will be clearer if you follow standard naming conventions (class name with leading capital).

For further understanding of static members, see the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members#static-members).

Answer (score -1):

I think this is the key line in the documentation:

> Only one copy of a static member exists, regardless of how many
>   instances of the class are created.

Only allowing access through the Class makes sense in light of the above.